# Selector for layout inside DrawerLayout doesn't work

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a view aligned to the bottom of a navigation drawer that is not in list.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/readscreen_bg">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/loading_layout"
            android:visibility="invisible">
                <ProgressBar
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_content"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/navdrw_bg"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/navigation_support_item_height"
            android:id="@+id/support_project"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:background="@drawable/support_project_selector"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_item_icon_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/navigation_item_icon_size"
                android:id="@+id/navigation_icon"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/navigation_item_icon_left_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/navigation_item_icon_right_margin"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_support"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/navdrw_bg"
                android:text="@string/navigation_support_project"
                android:textSize="@dimen/navigation_item_text_size"
                android:id="@+id/navigation_name"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/navigation_icon"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/support_project"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:divider="@null"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

It is, with id support_project. The problem is selector for this layout doesn't work.

**support_project_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <!-- Selected -->
        <item
            android:drawable="@color/navdrw_support_block_bg_pressed"
            android:state_focused="true"
            android:state_selected="true"/>

        <!-- Pressed -->
        <item
            android:drawable="@color/navdrw_support_block_bg_pressed"
            android:state_focused="false"
            android:state_selected="true"/>

        <!-- When not selected -->
        <item
            android:drawable="@color/navdrw_support_block_bg"/>

    </selector>
```

I was trying many variants and nothing helped. Selector **does** install color when view is not clicked but when it is clicked it doesn't change it's color.

But layout is clickable, I do receive click event and can process it. The problem is only with click/activate color.

Colors in selector for active and normal state are 100% completely different.

Comment: Have you tried android: duplicateParentState on the layout?

Comment: @AlexBalo I've just tried but it doesn't helped.

Comment: Can you change your selector using the state_pressed state? You didn't set it to true

Comment: @AlexBalo yes, I've just tried and it doesn't helped.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple aspects you are handling not so good, here.

First, your selector possible states:

You should have an `item` tag per state you want to customize and one different `android:state` value per item tag. So, remove your `android:state_focused` attributes from both states (selected and pressed).

On your `pressed` state, you are using `android:state_selected="true"` when you should be using `android:state_pressed="true"`. This will make your selector work when the item is actually pressed, not only when it is selected.

Second, in order to affect the selector to your `RelativeLayout`, you have to set it clickable by adding `android:clickable=true` attribute in your xml layout. `RelativeLayout` is not clickable by default, unlike a `Button`, for example.

For last, add `android:duplicateParentState="true"` to your `RelativeLayout` children `Views`, `ImageView` and `TextView`. This attribute allows the children to have the same state as the parent. When your `RelativeLayout` is selected or pressed, that state will be replicated by its children.

And you are done. Your selector is working.